# Find Pairs in recursive table

Tags: sql-server

I have the followign table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

I try to create a query which will return a list of pairs ID, ParentID. For example I have the followign data

```
ID  ParentID
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   3
5   3
15  8
```

I want when I search by ID = 5 to have the following list:

```
ID  ParentID
5   3
3   1
1   0
```

If I search by ID = 15 it should see that the sequence is boken and I will get the followign list.

```
ID  ParentID
15  8
```

I used a temporary table in order to make it work and my code is the following:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Pairs') is not null
    DROP TABLE #Pairs
create table #Pairs
( 
    ID INT,
    ParentID INT
)
Declare @ID integer = 5;
Declare @ParentID integer;
while (@ID > 0)
BEGIN
  SET @ParentID = null;             -- I set it to null so that I will be able to check in case the sequence is broken
  select @ID=ID, @ParentID=ParentID
  from MyTable
  where ID = @ID;

  if @ParentID IS NOT null 
  begin
  Insert into #Pairs (ID, ParentID) Values (@ID, @ParentID)
  SET @ID = @ParentID;
  end
  else
    SET @ID = 0;
END
SELECT * from #Pairs
```

It works but I am sure that there is a better way to do it. I found some strange queries which was suspposed to do something similar but I was not able to convert it in order to cover my needs.

For example I found the following Question but I was not able to convert it to work with my table. All the queries that I found had similar answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for recursive queries. See following example:

```
SELECT * INTO tab FROM (VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 0),
(3, 1),
(4, 3),
(5, 3),
(15, 8)) T(ID, ParentID);

DECLARE @whatAreYouLookingFor int = 5;

WITH Rec AS
(
    SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID=@whatAreYouLookingFor
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.* FROM tab T JOIN Rec R ON R.ParentID=T.ID
)
SELECT * FROM Rec;

DROP TABLE tab
```

**Output:**

```
ID  ParentID
--  --------
5   3
3   1
1   0
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver.